# What creates the vertical component of the angular momentum of the whole spinning wheel and axle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

I have been watching this Veritasium YouTube about Gyroscope Precession and I understand why the spinning wheel will rotate about the string. But now that the whole spinning wheel and axle is rotating about the string there must be an angular momentum component vector pointing upwards to the ceiling. But how is that vertical angular momentum component vector created?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ty9QSiVC2g0

Answer (score 0):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
[image]

Lets look at the angular momentum

you rotate the rotor about the Y axis with constant angular speed $~\Omega~$. the addition generalized coordinate of the gyro are the rotation about the X axis $~\theta~$ and the rotation about the Z axis  $~\psi~$. from here you obtain the transformation matrix between the gyro system and inertial system

$$\b S=\b S_X(\theta)\,\b S_Y(\Omega\,t)\,\b S_Z(\psi)\tag 1$$

with equation (1) you obtain the angular velocity vector

$$\b \omega=
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \Omega\,t \right) \cos \left( 
\psi \right) \dot\theta +\Omega\,\sin \left( \psi \right) 
\\ -\cos \left( \Omega\,t \right) \sin \left( \psi
 \right) \dot\theta +\Omega\,\cos \left( \psi \right) 
\\ \sin \left( \Omega\,t \right) \dot\theta +\dot\psi 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

the angular momentum $~\b L~$ is

$$\b L=\b \Theta\,\b\omega\quad\Rightarrow\\
\b L_Z=\Theta_Z\,\omega_Z=
\Theta_Z\left(\sin \left( \Omega\,t \right) \dot\theta +\dot\psi \right)$$

hench the torque $~\tau~$ that rotate the gyro about the Z axis is: $~\tau=\frac{d}{dt}L_Z~$

Comment: Many thanks for the mathematical proof but is there an explanation from a basic physics perspective? I can only envisage 2 angular momentum vectors that could be the cause of that of Lz  vector and that would be from the spinning wheel  (ie, angular momentum vector in the Y axis) and/or the weight of the system causing rotation such that angular momentum vector would point in the X axis (ie. in this local frame of reference). I cannot see how these angular momentum vectors could produce an angular momentum component vector pointing in the Z axis direction.